# Unable to select for only one condition for an if statement

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Trying to get only one condition to be true, if the first issue is proven right. The if condition is after a foreach loop. So the loop will check to see if each loop fits the criteria and give the respecive answer.

I've tried get the the information corrected using @isset and @switch.

```
  <!-- Like a quote -->
<div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            @auth                           
                @if($quote->userLike->count() > 0)                                
                    @foreach($quote->userLike as $like)
                        @if($like->pivot->user_id == $id)
                        <li class="list-inline-item">
                            <form  method="POST" action="{{route('likequote')}" class="likequote">
                            @csrf
                            <button class="btn btn-danger shadow-lg" id="savelike"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i>                             
                        </li>   
                        @endif  
                @endforeach  
                @else
                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <form  method="POST" action="{{route('likequote')}}" class="likequote">
                        @csrf
                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control col-md-4" name="likequote" id="likequote" value='{{$quote->id}}'>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary shadow-lg   " id="savelike"><i class="fas fa-heart"></button></i>
                        </form>                                 
                    </li>
                @endif
             @endauth
                <!-- Audio -->
                <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <source src="{{$quote->mp3_url}}" type="audio/mpeg">
                    Your browser does not support the audio tag.
                    </audio>
                </li>                                   
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
@else
```

Comment: What 's your exact issue? do you got any warning or issue....Just remove @ and check for issue or warnings...

Comment: explain more about your issue?Please ask your question explicit

Comment: I am trying to get a response where only one of the responses is produced. So if the `$like->pivot->user_id == $id` is true, the loop stops. However, since its a foreach loop, using a many-to-many relationship, if there is another relationship for another `user_id` then the result would get produced. I may be using the wrong function, but I am lost now.

Comment: @mohammadHosseini any input?